# How to setup local proxy with authentication for testing

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, proxy, localhost

I want to setup a local proxy with user and password for testing

Comment: Please dont post off topic questions... You can post ubuntu questions at askubuntu not here

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it with squid:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install squid3
```

Paste `admin:$apr1$kWA/DRFy$klaeXRe3S3jIPqc64HTMA0` into `/etc/squid/passwords` file

```
sudo chmod 777 /etc/squid/passwords
```

Backup default squid config file:

```
sudo mv /etc/squid/squid.conf /etc/squid/squid.conf.original
```

paste the below content in `/etc/squid/squid.conf`

```
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwords
auth_param basic realm Squid proxy-caching web server
auth_param basic credentialsttl 24 hours
auth_param basic casesensitive off
acl authenticated proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow authenticated
http_access deny all
dns_v4_first on
forwarded_for delete
via off
http_port 8888
```

Restart squid

```
sudo service squid restart
```

Proxy details:

- ip: localhost
- port: 8888
- user: admin
- password: 1234

Test using:

```
curl -x http://admin:1234@localhost:8888 http://icanhazip.com
```

References:
[1](https://gist.github.com/yvanin/ef831720112c1f6ee8c3)
[2](https://gist.github.com/jackblk/fdac4c744ddf2a0533278a38888f3caf)

Comment: Please dont answer off topic questions... He shall post ubuntu questions at askubuntu not here

Comment: @AlyMohamed okk